# Disable server side caching ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, caching

How can I disable absolutely all caching on for an asp.net website? I have problems with asp:literal caching its values and it's annoying as hell. Don't tell me it's a bad idea to do that, since it's for a development version only. I think it's called output caching, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you should describe exactly what is happening and what you want to happen, instead of guessing at names?

Comment: I've tried that, didn't get answers though. ASP.net is caching asp:literal values and i have to restart the debugger to update them when i change them in the source (refresh on the page isn't enough). I don't have any other explanation for this.

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the page or control in question for something like the following:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="18000" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

Remove the line.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such line. I've tried adding one with duration of 1 second, but then the page wouldn't display at all (maybe i needed to restart the debugger)